# NTFS Disk with error in S.M.A.R.T

Tags: 14.04, ntfs, fsck, smart

I have a NTFS disk where I store my data, after a problem with a bad IDE/SATA adapter (who was shutting down my disk) the S.M.A.R.T is showing errors.

I want to know what more I need to do to check and fix any error at this disk.

I've used fsck to check the disk but its not verbosely to me.

```
    andre@PITCAIRN:~$ sudo fsck /dev/sdb1
fsck from util-linux 2.20.1
Mounting volume... OK
Processing of $MFT and $MFTMirr completed successfully.
Checking the alternate boot sector... OK
NTFS volume version is 3.1.
NTFS partition /dev/sdb1 was processed successfully.
```

The S.M.A.R.T

```
SMART Attributes Data Structure revision number: 10
Vendor Specific SMART Attributes with Thresholds:
ID# ATTRIBUTE_NAME          FLAG     VALUE WORST THRESH TYPE      UPDATED  WHEN_FAILED RAW_VALUE
  1 Raw_Read_Error_Rate     0x000f   115   099   006    Pre-fail  Always       -       95292924
  3 Spin_Up_Time            0x0003   100   100   000    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
  4 Start_Stop_Count        0x0032   097   097   020    Old_age   Always       -       3419
  5 Reallocated_Sector_Ct   0x0033   100   100   036    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
  7 Seek_Error_Rate         0x000f   067   060   030    Pre-fail  Always       -       5425551
  9 Power_On_Hours          0x0032   093   093   000    Old_age   Always       -       6345
 10 Spin_Retry_Count        0x0013   100   100   097    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
 12 Power_Cycle_Count       0x0032   099   099   020    Old_age   Always       -       1501
183 Runtime_Bad_Block       0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
184 End-to-End_Error        0x0032   100   100   099    Old_age   Always       -       0
187 Reported_Uncorrect      0x0032   046   046   000    Old_age   Always       -       54
188 Command_Timeout         0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
189 High_Fly_Writes         0x003a   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
190 Airflow_Temperature_Cel 0x0022   062   048   045    Old_age   Always       -       38 (Min/Max 31/39)
194 Temperature_Celsius     0x0022   038   052   000    Old_age   Always       -       38 (0 19 0 0 0)
195 Hardware_ECC_Recovered  0x001a   041   022   000    Old_age   Always       -       95292924
197 Current_Pending_Sector  0x0012   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       20
198 Offline_Uncorrectable   0x0010   100   100   000    Old_age   Offline      -       20
199 UDMA_CRC_Error_Count    0x003e   200   200   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
240 Head_Flying_Hours       0x0000   100   253   000    Old_age   Offline      -       96499325213315
241 Total_LBAs_Written      0x0000   100   253   000    Old_age   Offline      -       2999278438
242 Total_LBAs_Read         0x0000   100   253   000    Old_age   Offline      -       866573403
```

And the error at S.M.A.R.T

```
SMART Error Log Version: 1
ATA Error Count: 54 (device log contains only the most recent five errors)
    CR = Command Register [HEX]
    FR = Features Register [HEX]
    SC = Sector Count Register [HEX]
    SN = Sector Number Register [HEX]
    CL = Cylinder Low Register [HEX]
    CH = Cylinder High Register [HEX]
    DH = Device/Head Register [HEX]
    DC = Device Command Register [HEX]
    ER = Error register [HEX]
    ST = Status register [HEX]
Powered_Up_Time is measured from power on, and printed as
DDd+hh:mm:SS.sss where DD=days, hh=hours, mm=minutes,
SS=sec, and sss=millisec. It "wraps" after 49.710 days.

Error 54 occurred at disk power-on lifetime: 6088 hours (253 days + 16 hours)
  When the command that caused the error occurred, the device was active or idle.

  After command completion occurred, registers were:
  ER ST SC SN CL CH DH
  -- -- -- -- -- -- --
  40 51 00 ff ff ff 0f  Error: UNC at LBA = 0x0fffffff = 268435455

  Commands leading to the command that caused the error were:
  CR FR SC SN CL CH DH DC   Powered_Up_Time  Command/Feature_Name
  -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --  ----------------  --------------------
  60 00 08 ff ff ff 4f 00      10:17:38.985  READ FPDMA QUEUED
  60 00 08 ff ff ff 4f 00      10:17:38.983  READ FPDMA QUEUED
  60 00 08 ff ff ff 4f 00      10:17:38.971  READ FPDMA QUEUED
  60 00 08 ff ff ff 4f 00      10:17:38.970  READ FPDMA QUEUED
  60 00 08 ff ff ff 4f 00      10:17:38.970  READ FPDMA QUEUED

Error 53 occurred at disk power-on lifetime: 6088 hours (253 days + 16 hours)
  When the command that caused the error occurred, the device was active or idle.

  After command completion occurred, registers were:
  ER ST SC SN CL CH DH
  -- -- -- -- -- -- --
  40 51 00 ff ff ff 0f  Error: UNC at LBA = 0x0fffffff = 268435455

  Commands leading to the command that caused the error were:
  CR FR SC SN CL CH DH DC   Powered_Up_Time  Command/Feature_Name
  -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --  ----------------  --------------------
  60 00 08 ff ff ff 4f 00      10:17:35.999  READ FPDMA QUEUED
  60 00 08 ff ff ff 4f 00      10:17:35.999  READ FPDMA QUEUED
  60 00 08 ff ff ff 4f 00      10:17:35.998  READ FPDMA QUEUED
  60 00 08 ff ff ff 4f 00      10:17:35.998  READ FPDMA QUEUED
  60 00 08 ff ff ff 4f 00      10:17:35.998  READ FPDMA QUEUED

Error 52 occurred at disk power-on lifetime: 6088 hours (253 days + 16 hours)
  When the command that caused the error occurred, the device was active or idle.

  After command completion occurred, registers were:
  ER ST SC SN CL CH DH
  -- -- -- -- -- -- --
  40 51 00 ff ff ff 0f  Error: UNC at LBA = 0x0fffffff = 268435455

  Commands leading to the command that caused the error were:
  CR FR SC SN CL CH DH DC   Powered_Up_Time  Command/Feature_Name
  -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --  ----------------  --------------------
  60 00 08 ff ff ff 4f 00      10:17:29.920  READ FPDMA QUEUED
  27 00 00 00 00 00 e0 00      10:17:29.918  READ NATIVE MAX ADDRESS EXT [OBS-ACS-3]
  ec 00 00 00 00 00 a0 00      10:17:29.909  IDENTIFY DEVICE
  ef 03 45 00 00 00 a0 00      10:17:29.909  SET FEATURES [Set transfer mode]
  27 00 00 00 00 00 e0 00      10:17:29.909  READ NATIVE MAX ADDRESS EXT [OBS-ACS-3]

Error 51 occurred at disk power-on lifetime: 6088 hours (253 days + 16 hours)
  When the command that caused the error occurred, the device was active or idle.

  After command completion occurred, registers were:
  ER ST SC SN CL CH DH
  -- -- -- -- -- -- --
  40 51 00 ff ff ff 0f  Error: UNC at LBA = 0x0fffffff = 268435455

  Commands leading to the command that caused the error were:
  CR FR SC SN CL CH DH DC   Powered_Up_Time  Command/Feature_Name
  -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --  ----------------  --------------------
  60 00 08 ff ff ff 4f 00      10:17:27.106  READ FPDMA QUEUED
  27 00 00 00 00 00 e0 00      10:17:27.104  READ NATIVE MAX ADDRESS EXT [OBS-ACS-3]
  ec 00 00 00 00 00 a0 00      10:17:27.095  IDENTIFY DEVICE
  ef 03 45 00 00 00 a0 00      10:17:27.095  SET FEATURES [Set transfer mode]
  27 00 00 00 00 00 e0 00      10:17:27.095  READ NATIVE MAX ADDRESS EXT [OBS-ACS-3]

Error 50 occurred at disk power-on lifetime: 6088 hours (253 days + 16 hours)
  When the command that caused the error occurred, the device was active or idle.

  After command completion occurred, registers were:
  ER ST SC SN CL CH DH
  -- -- -- -- -- -- --
  40 51 00 ff ff ff 0f  Error: UNC at LBA = 0x0fffffff = 268435455

  Commands leading to the command that caused the error were:
  CR FR SC SN CL CH DH DC   Powered_Up_Time  Command/Feature_Name
  -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --  ----------------  --------------------
  60 00 08 ff ff ff 4f 00      10:17:24.293  READ FPDMA QUEUED
  60 00 08 ff ff ff 4f 00      10:17:24.279  READ FPDMA QUEUED
  60 00 08 ff ff ff 4f 00      10:17:24.279  READ FPDMA QUEUED
  60 00 08 ff ff ff 4f 00      10:17:24.279  READ FPDMA QUEUED
  60 00 08 ff ff ff 4f 00      10:17:24.279  READ FPDMA QUEUED
```

I'm running the extended self test at this disk with it UNMOUNTED.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have 20 bad sectors on the drive.  They may simply have become corrupt for example, due to sudden power loss in the middle of a write.  You can try to write zeros to them and see if they come back.  You will need to identify the sector numbers in question, which you can see from the error log there, the first one is 268435455.  First, try to read it to verify it is bad:

```
sudo dd if=/dev/sdb bs=512 of=/dev/null count=1 iflag=direct skip=268435455
```

If this is a 4k sector drive, use 4096 for bs= instead of 512.  This should give an error.  If it does, write it with zeros:

```
sudo dd if=/dev/zero bs=512 of=/dev/sdb seek=268435455 count=1 oflag=direct
```

Double check the command before hitting enter; if you don't get it exactly right, you can destroy data.

Repeat this for each of the sectors in the error log, then check the SMART status again.  The pending count should go down.  If the reallocated count goes up, then the sectors were physically damaged and you should replace the drive.  If not, it should be fine.  You might try running the long SMART selftest to find more bad sectors.

Comment: How can I take a look in all S.M.A.R.T logs to collect all LBAs? I will transfer data to another disk and after I will do the zero fill in the LBAs with error.

Comment: @AndréM.Faria, if you are going to transfer the data to another disk, then it may be easier to simply zero out the entire original disk, then copy the data back, rather than look up each individual bad sector.  In that case, omit the seek and count arguments and it will zero the entire disk.  Then you can reformat it, and copy your files back.

Comment: Ok, so I will do that, just for curiosity, how can I check if disk is formated with 4k sector?

Comment: fdisk -l made the magic 'Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes'

Comment: After moving all data, and verified with hashdeep, I did a DD, who last for 30 hours, the pending count decreased to 0 and the reallocated count still 0, for my pleasure. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You've already done anything that's necessary to repair the drive. SMART is a monitoring system that is a feature of the hard drive controller, so the only thing the operating system does is showing the data collected by the SMART system. You can't reset it, so if SMART has detected something that is considered as wrong it will be remembered forever. Errors detected by SMART are not necessarily a sign of a failing drive, however it is possible that there is indeed something wrong. In any case make sure you create good backups which you should do anyway.